# NSIS Installer Run Batch File

Tags: nsis

Trying to run a batch file at the end of an installation, everything works great except this file won't run.

```
section "Startup"
    Exec '"$0" /C "C:\Program Files\placeholder\startup\startup.bat"'
sectionEnd
```

Everything gets deposited in the right spot, using absolute pathing to call this. I asked for administrator privileges at the start,

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)
```

Just copying from the example NSIS installer provided [here](https://gist.github.com/cpoDesign/3a2af312b319da9e4fc6)

The file is there so I must be making a mistake with the file path or missing some parameter. Been trying a lot of permutations like nsExec but not sure my mistake. Hopefully this is a simple mistake and will aid others in the same boat at some time.

Comment: What is $0 here? Why are you hard coding Program Files?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information I would guess that this is a 64-bit Windows machine and filesystem redirection is causing your 32-bit installer to access the wrong program files directory.

The code you posted is also problematic because we don't know what `$0` is. I assume you failed to post the code where it expands %comspec%. To rule out this, replace `$0` with `$sysdir\cmd.exe`.

Ideally your installer should extract the batch file to the destination directory:

```
Section
SetOutPath $InstDir 
File batch.bat
ExecWait '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /C if 1==1 "$InstDir\batch.bat"'
SectionEnd
```

If you must access the 64-bit folder you can disable the redirection but this is not recommended:

```
!include x64.nsh
Section 
${DisableX64FSRedirection}
ExecWait ... $ProgramFiles64\... 
${EnableX64FSRedirection}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: This was the solution, I wasn't really understanding $0 in this context. I also removed the hardcoded file path. So the solution for me looks like 

Exec '$sysdir\cmd.exe /C "$PROGRAMFILES\path_placeholder\startup.bat"'

To run a batch file during installation. Thank you to Whitesoft and Anders and I hope others find this answer useful as well.

Comment: If it worked then you should mark it as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should give us more information to solve this problem.

Based on current information, I guess there are two reasons:

1. "C:\Program Files" is a path for 64-bit programs, but NSIS installer is a 32-bit program, so this path will be redirected to "C:\Program Files (x86)". You can use the solution from Anders to solve it.
2. Your batch file may contains relative paths. When you run your batch file from the NSIS installer, your working directory is not as same as your batch file. Due to this, some command cannot run correctly. You can use %~dp0 to solve it.